# How do I dynamically access or render Children in an Angular Component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component called wrapper and this is to be reused with different child components. I referred [this SO question](/questions/51171350/angular-pass-a-component-as-ng-template-of-another-component) and [this article](https://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders/). But they seem to address only if I know which child component I would be rendering before hand. But in my case, I might even just pass a `div` or `h2` in there.

Here's the minimal reproduction code

```html
<app-wrapper>
  <app-edit-address></app-edit-address>
</app-wrapper>

<app-wrapper>
  <div>
    <label>Edit Email</label>
    <input />
  </div>
</app-wrapper>

<app-wrapper>
  <h2>
    Unauthorized 
  </h2>
</app-wrapper>
```

In React I can easily render them just by writing `{props.children}` but Angular I don't know how. How can I render children dynamically without knowing the children before hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called `Content Projection` in Angular. You can simply use `ng-content` to project anything.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-wrapper',
  template: `
    <div class="wrapper">
       <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class WrapperComponent {}
```

And you can use it any way you like

```html
<app-wrapper>
  <app-edit-address></app-edit-address>
</app-wrapper>

<app-wrapper>
  <div>
    <label>Edit Email</label>
    <input />
  </div>
</app-wrapper>

<app-wrapper>
  <h2>
    Unauthorized 
  </h2>
</app-wrapper>
```

Whatever you pass between opening and closing tags will be projected into where `ng-content` is.

Comment: @Pushkin if you need to do more than this, let me know. This should solve your initial question.

Comment: Sweet! It works. Thank you for also telling me what it's called. It will definitely help others.

Comment: Awesome, happy to help :)